# difference between jsf beans and ejb beans

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

I need some clarification. I know how to work with JSF and its corresponding session beans, but i am getting confused with EJB. What is the difference between the beans introduced with EJB and the session beans used with JSF (for ejb i know about the stateless/full session beans and entity beans, entity manager, etc.). What i just dont get is when to use EJB and when to use jsf beans. Aside from the entity beans, both the ejb stateful/less session beans seem similar to the jsf session beans. I've read about injection ejb's into jsf, but why not just use ejb in conjunction with jsf beans? I hope you can understand my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, we need to know about the difference between **JSF** and **EJB** beans.

1. **JSF beans** are `POJO classes` which used to read the component value of JSF. There are two type of beans in JSF:

   - **Managed bean** is about how a java bean is created and initialized. As you know, JSF uses the Lazy initialization model. It means that the bean in the particular scope **is created and initialized** not at the moment when the scope is started, but **on-demand**, i.e. when the bean is first time required.
   - **Backing bean** is about the **role a particular managed** bean plays. This is a role to be a server-side representation of the components located on the page. Usually, the backing beans have a request scope, but it is not a restriction.
2. **EJB Bean** is a server-side component that **encapsulates the business logic** of an application. The business logic is the code that fulfills the purpose of the application.

Mainly, there are three types of session beans:

1.**Statefull** session bean

2.**Stateless** session bean

3.**Singleton** session bean(ejb 3.1)

Answer (score 11):

There is indeed some confusion between the different types of managed beans in Java EE. To add to the confusion, Java EE 6 has introduced a third kind of managed bean: a CDI bean.

In this answer I try to explain the differences and similarities a little: [How do CDI and EJB compare? interact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684112/how-do-cdi-and-ejb-compare-interact/4705840#4705840)

Briefly said, JSF managed beans mainly don't offer support for transactions, which is something you often need when working with business logic and especially JPA.

Also note that the term `session` as in session scoped managed beans is a completely different kind of session than the one the term in stateless and statefull session beans refers to.

Answer (score -1):

There is another gread answer on the site where the differences of CDI and EJB are explained. It helps a great deal when you finally grasp the whole picture. [Where to use EJB 3.1 and CDI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487987/where-to-use-ejb-3-1-and-cdi)