# How do CDI and EJB compare? interact?

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm having a tough time understanding how the two interact and where the boundary between them lies. Do they overlap? Are there redundancies between them?

I know there are annotations associated with both, but I haven't been able to find a complete list for both with brief descriptions. Not sure if this would help clear up how they differ or where they overlap.

Really just confused. I (think I) understand EJB reasonably well, I guess I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what CDI brings to the table and how it supplants or enhances what EJB already offers.

Comment: This question sorts top on Google's "EJB CDI difference" search, but I found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487987/where-to-use-ejb-3-1-and-cdi clearer

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**CDI:** it is about dependency injection. It means that you can inject interface implementation anywhere. This object can be anything, it can be not related to EJB. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjcxv.html) is an example of how to inject random generator using CDI. There is nothing about EJB. You are going to use CDI when you want to inject non-EJB services, different implementations or algorithms (so you don't need EJB there at all).
**EJB:** you do understand, and probably you are confused by `@EJB` annotation - it allows you to inject implementation into your service or whatever. The main idea is that class, where you inject, should be managed by EJB container.
Seems that CDI does understand what EJB is, so in Java EE 6 compliant server, in your servlet you can write both

```
@EJB EJBService ejbService;
```

and

```
@Inject EJBService ejbService;
```

that's what can make you confusing, but that's probably the only thing which is the bridge between EJB and CDI.

When we are talking about CDI, you can inject other objects into CDI managed classes (they just should be created by CDI aware frameworks).

What else CDI offers... For instance, you use Struts 2 as MVC framework (just example), and you are limited here, even using EJB 3.1 - you can't use `@EJB` annotation in Struts action, it is not managed by container. But when you add Struts2-CDI plugin, you can write there `@Inject` annotation for the same thing (so no more JNDI lookup needed). This way it enhances EJB power, but as I mentioned before, what you inject with CDI - it does not matter if it is related to EJB or not, and that's its power.

PS. updated link to the example

Comment: Are @EJB and @Inject truly functionally equivalent? I think it was the overlap of injection methods between CDI and some of the rest of the Java EE acronym soup that confused me. More reading seems to indicate that there is hope to align the annotations.

Comment: @Maxym When you use @ Inject, how can you ensure that the @ Stateless or any other server side component of EJB still use the features like Pooling or concurrency that is offered by the container.  I hope this is not offered by CDI right?

Comment: @Bala: CDI does not offer pooling... look at [CDI with or without EJB3.1](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/cdi_with_or_without_ejb), hope it answers your question..

Comment: @KorayTugay: CDI is a Java EE feature, so any Java EE 6 compliant server has it (Glassfish 3.0.1+ is not mistaken, JBoss 6+ etc.) You can take a look at JBoss Weld, a reference CDI implementation which you can use in for instance Tomcat...

Answer (score 199):

It is currently indeed a bit confusing as there are now multiple component models in Java EE. They are **CDI**, **EJB3** and **JSF Managed Beans**.

**CDI** is the new kid on the block. CDI beans feature `dependency injection`, `scoping` and an `event bus`. CDI beans are the most flexible with respect to injection and scoping. The event bus is very lightweight and very well suited for even the simplest of web applications. In addition to this, CDI also exposes a very advanced feature called `portable extensions`, which is a kind of plug-in mechanism for vendors to provide extra functionality to Java EE that can be made available on all implementations (Glassfish, JBoss AS, Websphere, etc).

**EJB3** beans were retrofitted from the old legacy EJB2 component model<sup>*</sup> and were the first beans in Java EE to be managed beans via an annotation. EJB3 beans feature `dependency injection`, `declarative transactions`,  `declarative security`, `pooling`, `concurrency control`, `asynchronous execution` and `remoting`.

Dependency injection in EJB3 beans is not as flexible as in CDI beans and EJB3 beans have no concept of scoping. However, EJB3 beans are transactional and pooled by default<sup>**</sup>, two very useable things that CDI has chosen to leave in the domain of EJB3. The other mentioned items are also not available in CDI. EJB3 has no event bus of its own though, but it does have a special type of bean for listening to messages; the message driven bean. This can be used to receive messages from the Java Messaging System or from any other system that has a JCA resource adaptor. Using full blown messaging for simple events is far more heavyweight than the CDI event bus and EJB3 only defines a listener, not a producer API.

**JSF Managed Beans** have existed in Java EE ever since JSF was included. They too feature `dependency injection` and `scoping`. JSF Managed Beans introduced the concept of declarative scoping. Originally the scopes were rather limited and in the same version of Java EE where EJB3 beans could already be declared via annotations, JSF Managed Beans still had to be declared in XML. The current version of JSF Managed Beans are also finally declared via an annotation and the scopes are expanded with a view scope and the ability to create custom scopes. The view scope, which remembers data between requests to the **same** page is a unique feature of JSF Managed Beans.

Apart from the view scope, there is very little still going for JSF Managed Beans in Java EE 6. The missing view scope in CDI there is unfortunate, since otherwise CDI would have been a perfect super set of what JSF Managed Beans offer. **Update**: In Java EE 7/JSF 2.2 a [CDI compatible @ViewScoped](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087) has been added, making CDI indeed that perfect super set. **Update 2**: In JSF2.3 the JSF managed beans have been deprecated in favour of CDI managed beans.

With EJB3 and CDI the situation is not that clear cut. The EJB3 component model and API offers a lot of services that CDI does not offer, so typically EJB3 cannot be replaced by CDI. On the other hand, CDI can be used in combination with EJB3 - e.g. adding scope support to EJBs.

Reza Rahman, expert group member and implementor of a CDI implementation called CanDI, has frequently hinted that the services associated with the EJB3 component model can be retrofitted as a set of CDI annotations. If that were to happen, all managed beans in Java EE could become CDI beans. This does not mean that EJB3 disappears or becomes obsolete, but just that its functionality will be exposed via CDI instead of via EJB's own annotations like @Stateless and @EJB.

**Update**

David Blevins of TomEE and OpenEJB fame explains the differences and similarities between CDI and EJB very well on his blog: [CDI, when to break out the EJBs](http://blog.dblevins.com/2012/11/cdi-when-to-break-out-ejbs.html)

<sub>* 
Although it's just an increment in version number, EJB3 beans were for the most part a completely different kind of bean: a simple pojo that becomes a "managed bean" by applying a simple single annotation, vs the model in EJB2 where a heavyweight and overly verbose XML deployment descriptor was required for each and every bean, in addition to the bean being required to implement various extremely heavyweight and for the most part meaningless component interfaces.</sub>

<sub>** Stateless session beans are typically pooled, stateful session beans typically not (but they can be). For both types pooling is thus optional and the EJB spec does not mandate it either way.</sub>

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your statements that "EJB3 beans have no concept of scoping" and that "EJB3 has no event bus of its own though". How does this fit in with [David Blevin's](http://blog.dblevins.com/2012/11/cdi-when-to-break-out-ejbs.html) claim that "EJBs **are** CDI beans and therefore have all the benefits of CDI" ? Has anything changed in this respect between when you wrote your answer and when David wrote his Blog entry?

Comment: It's because of the perhaps somewhat confusing concept that there are  *actually* not really "CDI beans", but there are services applied to managed beans. For the sake of discussion people (and myself thus) refer to them as "CDI beans' anyway. Before CDI, EJB beans had no explicit scoping. As David explains, Stateful is implicitly any scope (and thus no scope in particular). Now with CDI available, EJB beans can take advantage of the CDI provided scopes. Without the CDI spec, so when solely looking at the EJB spec, there are no explicit scopes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "there are services applied to managed beans" ? Does it mean there is actually no such thing as a CDI bean? It is just some providing extra features on either a POJO - EJB - or a JSF Managed Bean? Like being able to use Inject annotation in a JSF Managed Bean?

Comment: @Chris to further clarify from an EJB spec perspective we made the deliberate decision from the start of CDI to require that EJB implementations must support 100% of the CDI feature set on EJBs. Every aspect of CDI works on EJBs with the exception of scopes which we had to limit to Stateful beans only.

Comment: Note that JSF 2.2 now provides javax.faces.view.ViewScoped, a CDI extension which is essentially a port of the JSF view scope to CDI.  With this, CDI is a full drop-in replacement for JSF Managed Beans.

Comment: "Stateless session beans are always pooled" is incorrect. See EJB 3.1 spec: "Since stateless session bean instances are typically pooled..." (4.3.10.2 Stateless Session Beans), "When the container no longer needs the instance (usually when the container wants to reduce
the number of instances in the method-ready pool)" (4.7.1 Stateless Session Bean State Diagram). Wildfly 8-9 doesn't pool SLSB by default, Wildfly 10 does.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov Indeed, you're right. Pooling itself is strictly speaking not an explicit feature, just something that as the spec text indicates "typically" happens. In the early beta versions of JBoss EAP 7 (i.e. WF 8-9) pooling of stateless beans was effectively disabled (I think the pool size was set to 0). In later beta versions and the final release this was reversed.

Answer (score -1):

Albert Einstein: `If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough`

Ejbs and CDI are pretty simple to understand.

Ejbs:

1. Will always be annotated by scope qualifiers, for instance, @Stateless, @Stateful, @Request etc
2. The instances of Ejbs is controlled by the Java EE framework and pooled. It is the duty of EE framework to provide the instances for the consumer.

`@Stateless`

```
 public class CarMaker(){
    public void createCar(Specification specs){
        Car car = new Car(specs);
    }
}
```

The CarMaker is Annotated with specific Ejbs scope, therefore, it's Ejb

CDI:

1. Not managed entirely by EE framework, instances has to be created by yourself.
2. It is always dependent. let me explain "Dependent" with example:

   `class Specification {
     private String color;
     private String model;
     //- Getter and Setter
   }`

The `Specification` class is CDI, since it is not annotated with Ejb scopes and also this has to initialized by your code not EE framework. 
One point to be noted here is that since we didn't Annotated the `Specification` class, it is by default Annotated by `@Dependent` annotation.

```
@Dependent  <- By default added 
class Specification { ... }
```

`Further reading:` You need to study more between Ejbs scope annotation and CDI scope annotation, that will further clear the conceptl

Comment: Einstein also said: _"Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler"_ you can (should) replace 'made' with 'explained' here.