# ManagedBean method doesn't work in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have written two managedbean classes named `Message` and `HelloWorld`. They are as follow :

Message.java :

```
package com.bean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "message", eager = true)
@RequestScoped
@SessionScoped
public class Message {

    private String message = "Hello World!";

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.bean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld")
@RequestScoped
@SessionScoped
public class HelloWorld {

   @ManagedProperty(value="#{message}")
   private Message messageBean;
   private String msg;


   public HelloWorld() {
      System.out.println("HelloWorld started!"); 
   }

   public void setMessage(String message) {
       this.msg = message;
   }

   public String getMessage() {
      if(messageBean != null){
         msg = messageBean.getMessage();
      }       
      return msg;
   }

   public void setMessageBean(Message message) {
      this.messageBean = message;
   }

   public void showMsg(){
      // String str="I am a demo string!";
       System.out.println(msg +" I am from showMsg()");
   }  
}
```

And, my `index.xhtml` here:

```
<body>
    #{helloWorld.message}
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Show Msg" action="#{helloworld.showMsg}"/>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

`#{helloWorld.message}` prints the message perfectly. But the `<h:commandButton> does not invoke the method`showMsg()`. What's the problem?

Comment: `#{helloWorld.showMsg}` - note the capital W

Comment: And you should either use `RequestScope` or `SessionScope` - both together do not make any sense.

Comment: FYI : forthermore, `eager = true` is only applicable to application scoped JSF managed beans. It is as good as it is removed from the `@ManagedBean` annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `action="#{helloworld.showMsg}"` with lowercase `w` for world. EL is case sensitive. Change to `action="#{helloWorld.showMsg}"`.

Also, what you have been told in the comments, you can't use both `@RequestScoped` and `@SessionScoped`, pick one. And, `action` attribute should resolve to String (`showMsg()` returns `void`), it is used to perform navigation. If you just want something done, without navigation, use `actionListener` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A ManagedBean annotation doesn't work, if someone accidentally **uses a different import**, for example `javax.annotation.ManagedBean`. It must be `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`.

Comment: This is not an answer to this actual problem... It could however show the same behaviour if you make this error. In addition, your 'answer' is in several other Q/A, amongst others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations/15058240

Answer (score 0):

`EL` is case sensitive in `jsf`. You have used `action="#{helloworld.showMsg}` with lowercase `w` and you declare `@ManagedBean(name="helloWorld")` with uppercase `W`. Try it, `action="#{helloWorld.showMsg}`.