# Container create several instance when @Inject and JSF

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean

I'm creating two beans, make inject first bean to second bean.
Second bean make set method for first bean.
Also second bean bean called from JSF.

I need to container create one instance for access from second bean and JSF page.

Result page not include data from first bean, that has been set from second bean.

I think container create two instance. But why?

Thanks.

Code:

### first bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="a")
@Stateful

class A{

private String thing;

public String getThing();
public String setThing();

}
```

### second bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="b")
@SessionScoped
@Stateful

class B{

@Inject
private A a;

a.setThing();

}
```

### JSF page

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{a.thing}" />
```

Comment: Sorry, of course, annotations ManagedBeans, Stateful and SessionScoped was  written before class. But still does not work.

Comment: Check the packages of your annotations and use the link in my answer to check if you have the correct combinations

Answer (score 2):

Your `@ManagedBeans` (it is @MangagedBean, without an s), `@SessionScoped` and `@Stateful` are positioned wrong. They should be above the class. And if you start using @Inject, might I suggest moving to the CDI based annotation @Named and its corresponding @SessionScoped (in a different pacakge). For the correct packages of annotations see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations)