# p:datatable select row listener not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Initially a button is disabled, and I want it to get enabled when I select a row in the datatable, but the listener is not working and I can't find the problem...

This is how the xhtml file looks like:

```
<h:form id="form" class="formulario">
        ...
        <p:dataTable value="#{queryBean.offs}" var="offer" selection="#{queryBean.oferta}" rowKey="#{offer.offerNumber}" tableStyle="width:auto" >
                <f:facet name="header">Ofertas disponibles</f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{queryBean.rowSelected}" />

                ...

        </p:dataTable>

            <center><br/>
            <h:commandButton id="botonReserva" value="Reservar" disabled="true" >
                <p:ajax process="form" update="form" resetValues="true" />
            </h:commandButton>

                ...
            </center>
</h:form>
```

And this is the bean's listener

```
...

public void rowSelected(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    System.out.println("Working");
    //Not printing anything
}

...
```

I know I'm not updating the button but it is because it doesn't work, so first I want to know how to solve this. After I solve the problem I would know how to enable the button.

What could be the problem?

SOLUTION: It was because I was using a datatable with radio buttons, and I should have used `event="rowSelectRadio"` instead of `event="rowSelect"`

Comment: Are you sure it's not printing anything? If you're running with an application server as is typical, the console output may, or may not be logged. If it is logged it may not be to a place you expect.

Perhaps try creating a file in your rowSelected method instead.

Comment: @Sam i'll try, but other prints in other methods work

Comment: Then that's not it.

Comment: Maybe add  <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" /> to the form and add update=":form:messages" as an attribute to the ajax element. May give you some more logging to work from

Comment: read all this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: @Sam nothing happens

Comment: @Kukeltje I read it and it didn't help. I don't know what's wrong... I'm using session scope, it doesn't matter right?

Comment: IF you have the 'wrong' sessionscoped annotation it does matter...

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations

Comment: Solved it!! It was because I was using a datatable with radio buttons, and I should have used `event="rowSelectRadio"` instead of `event="rowSelect"` ...

My bad