# f:ajax still refreshes the whole page

Tags: ajax, jsf-2.2

I try to AJAXify a simple commandButton in order to send AJAX request without refreshing the whole page. My xhtml file includes the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{test.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h2>
            <h:outputText id="output" value="#{test.sayWelcome}" />
        </h2>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My backing bean is the following:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ViewScoped
@Named("test")
public class TestBackingBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSayWelcome() {
        // check if null?
        if ("".equals(name) || name == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return "Ajax message : Welcome " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I click on commandButton the form is submitted and the whole page is refreshed.

I would like to avoid using additional JSF frameworks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **YOU** update the `@form` which is sort of the whole page (besides the body and head) so it seems as designed (by you) that the 'whole page' is updated. Not related: you use the wrong `@Viewscoped` for the `@Named`, use the `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` one

Comment: Indeed the form is sort of the whole page. But when I click  on commandButton the form is submitted without using AJAX. That is, if I press F5 (for e.g. in Firefox), I get this message:

"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

Comment: so the behaviour (debugged network traffic?) is identical with or without the `f:ajax`

Comment: Yes, the network traffic is identical with the one without f:ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tried the execute and render properties:

```
 <h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{test.name}"></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action=#{test.sayWelcome()}>
        <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" />
    </h:commandButton>

</h:form>
<h2> <!-- Outside the Form! -->
   <h:outputText id="output" value="#{test.message}" />
</h2>
```

Bean:

```
public class TestBackingBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private String message;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String value) {
        this.message = value;
    }

    public void sayWelcome() {
        // check if null?
        if ("".equals(name) || name == null) {
            message = "";
        } else {
            message = "Ajax message : Welcome " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the exact code but the result remains the same.

Comment: I just update the method "sayWelcome" and the message set/get.

Comment: And what if you use `@form` for both attributes?

Comment: if we add <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />, refesh all but no message returned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using the wrong `@ViewScoped`. It's [a mess that's a long time in the making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations/15058240#15058240), so condolences I guess.

The version of `@ViewScoped` you have there wasn't meant to be used with CDI's `@Named`. As a result, you really don't have a viewscoped bean there - the bean is in the implicit CDI `@Dependent` scope which will behave a little like the `@RequestScoped` scope.

**In short:** use the `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` annotation instead and your bean will behave properly.