# Error deploying on Glassfish v.3 after using @SessionScoped

Tags: jsf, cdi, session-scope

I am new to JSF, Java EE and am having abit of a problem with a small test case I am trying out with  Faces.xml, JSF and ManagedBeans..

I have a managedBean called beanManager.java and in it, I have two fields(name and testname) and a method called testcase1() that just returns a string. Now, in the frontpage.xhtml, I have an input text box that gets  a name from a user and once the user clicks the submit button, the testcase1() method is called and all it does is just set the testname field of the BeanManager.java class with the user's input but for some reasons-obviously why I am sending this message- when the user enter's the name and hits the search button the page navigates to the displaypage.xhtml and the page displays nothing. It is supposed to show the name entered by the user but it is blank. I was advised to use @SessionScoped instead of @RequestScoped but the problem now is that when I deploy my Java EE application on glassfish, i get the following error:

```
Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: 
Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
```

Below are my files..

**BeanManager.java**

```
    import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;


    @ManagedBean(name = "user")
    @SessionScoped

public class BeanManager {
    private String name = "";
    private String testname = "";


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String testcase1(){
        setTestname(this.name);
        return "test1";
    }


    public String getTestname() {
        return testname;
    }

    public void setTestname(String testname) {
        this.testname = testname;
    }

}
```

**frontpage.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/origin.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:view>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" required = "true"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton

                    action="#{user.testcase1()}"
                    value="Search"></h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
            </f:view>


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

**displaypage.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/origin.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
       <h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputText value="#{user.testname}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="back" value="GoBack" action="frontpage"/>
       </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/frontpage.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{user.testcase1()}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>test1</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/displaypage.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
         </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/displaypage.xhtml</from-view-id>
            <navigation-case>
                <from-outcome>GoBack</from-outcome>
                <to-view-id>/frontpage.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the CDI annotation `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` with the JSF `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`. You either go pure JSF with

- `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`(naming) and `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` (scoping)

  OR Pure CDI
- `javax.inject.Named` (naming) and `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`(scoping)

Related:

- [Java EE 6 @javax.annotation.ManagedBean vs. @javax.inject.Named vs. @javax.faces.ManagedBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces)

Comment: It works now but it seems like the name suggests, the SessionScoped prevents changes. Suppose I try action = "#{user.testcase2()}" instead of action = #{user.testcase1()} and I save it, everytime I compile and package, I get the action = #{user.testcase1()} instead of the updated action = #{user.testcase2()} how to effect changes?

Comment: Your edits not showing up on your physical file on your disk has nothing to do with the scope of your managed bean. Clean and rebuild your project in your ide