# Access sessionscoped managedbean values in requestscoped/viewscoped managedbean

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean

I'm trying to access an object in my sessioncontroller (sessionscoped bean) from a managedbean. The sessionobject gets created when you log in. Then when I try to persist from the requestscoped bean and I need the login-object from the sessioncontroller but when I debug it's always null.

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
// ??? @RequestScoped
public class BoekingController {

@Inject
private ZoekService zoekService;
@Inject
private BetaalwijzeService betaalwijzeService;
@EJB
private transient BoekingService boekingService;
@ManagedProperty("#{sessionController}")
private SessionController sessionController;

public void init() {
    if (betaalwijzeId > 0) {
        betaalwijze = betaalwijzeService.findToegestandBetaalwijze(betaalwijzeId);
    }

    reis = zoekService.findReis(reisId);

    if (aantalPersonen > 0) {
        instellenBoeking(aantalPersonen, betaalwijze, new Klant(1, "Test", "test@test.be", "test"), reis);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have hardcoded the object myself and persistence works, I just can't get the variable from the sessionController posted below.

**SessionController**

```
@SessionScoped
@Named(value = "sessionController")
public class SessionController implements Serializable{
Klant klant;

public Klant getKlant() {
    return klant;
}
public void setKlant(Klant klant) {
    this.klant = klant;
}
```

On pages I can access the sessionobject by using:#{sessionController.klantNaam}

Comment: Mixing different types of annotations is not a good practice.. [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces)

Answer (score 0):

The annotation [`ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html), as explained in the linked javadoc, should be used  to inject a JSF bean annotated with `ManagedBean`.

Use `Inject` annotation for injecting a CDI bean.