# JSF javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'home' resolved to null

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2

my app is cosist:

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Date Input of Users</title>
</h:head>

<body>

    <p:fieldset legend="name of home">

        <!-- form to insert a user data -->
        <h:form>

            <b>name of User:</b>
            <h:inputText value="#{home.name}"/><br/>

            <p:commandButton action="#{home.res}" ajax="false"      
                value="Save" />                                         <!-- button to save --> 
            <p />

        </h:form>


    </p:fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```

my bean is ->

```
package prova;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean

public class Home {

    //fields
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //change a page
    public String res(){
        return ("results");
    }
}
```

but when click a button of save , my server tomcat return a error and not a page
the error is:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'home' resolved to null
```

thanks all and sorry of my english

Comment: Looks like your bean is not instatiated correctly. Try to add a constructor with no Parameter.

Comment: create a costructor -> public home(){} ... but error persist T.T... not change errors T.T

Answer (score 0):

Change the import of that bean to:

```
javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

**See also:**

- [Java EE 6 @javax.annotation.ManagedBean vs. @javax.inject.Named vs. @javax.faces.ManagedBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces)

Comment: thanks :) ... now fuction ... thanks senpai :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: okay sorry ... my problem is connect to error of import path ... correct to path of import -> application run