# p:menuItem in p:menuBar does nothing when clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The `p:menuBar` and it's `p:menuItem`s are generated at runtime. They render correctly and function perfectly with the exception that when any choice from the menu is clicked, nothing happens.

My `index.xhtml` is quite simple.  It's just a `p:tabView` that composites my `dataentry.xhtml` in via a `ui:include`.  The components on `dataentry.xhtml` are where the trouble is happening.

```
//dataentry.xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="dataEntryForm">
        <p:menubar id="menuBar" binding="#{dataEntryBean.menuBar}" />
        <p:dashboard id="dashboard" binding="#{dataEntryBean.dashboard}"/>
    </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

Here's the method that generates the `p:menuBar`.  Again, all of this renders on the page correctly, it just doesn't do anything when you click on something.

```
    private @NotNull Menubar spawnMenuBar() {
        final MenuModel MODEL = new DefaultMenuModel();
        {
            final DefaultSubMenu SM = new DefaultSubMenu("Create New...", "ui-icon-circle-plus");
            Arrays.stream(Type.values()).forEach(CT -> {
                final String CT_ALT = CT.toInitialCaps();
                final DefaultMenuItem DMI = new DefaultMenuItem(CT_ALT + " Card");
                DMI.setId("createNew" + CT_ALT + "Type");
                DMI.setParam("TYPE", CT.name());
                DMI.setTitle("Creates a new " + CT_ALT + " type panel in the dashboard.");
                DMI.setCommand("#{dataEntryBean.addNewTypePanel(param.get('TYPE'))}");
                SM.addElement(DMI);
            });
            MODEL.addElement(SM);
        }
        {
            final DefaultSubMenu SM = new DefaultSubMenu("Global Actions...", "ui-icon-alert");
            // Implementation removed for brevity's sake...
            MODEL.addElement(SM);
        }
        final Menubar MENU = new Menubar();
        MENU.setModel(MODEL);
        return MENU;
    }
```

...and, finally, here's the method that all of those `p:menuItem`s in the first `p:subMenu` are supposed to invoke.

```
public void addNewTypePanel(final String TYPE) {
    System.out.println("Method Call: addNewTypePanel(" + TYPE + ")");
    // Implementation removed for brevity's sake...
}
```

That `println()` in `addNewTypePanel()` never appears.

Bizarrely (and, I suspect, unrelated), the `println()` on the first line of this bean's constructor appears twice (and then a 3rd time when the appropriate tab in the `p:tabView` is loaded).

Any ideas?
`doHope(HopeSeverity.VERY_HARD);`

---

Edit #1: Based on Kukeltje's suggestion, I re-tested this code by commenting out the `p:tabView` entirely and copying the `h:form` from `dataentry.xhmtl` (see code block below).  Unfortunately, the issue (issues?) were the same.  Still no response on click, still see the bean's constructor being invoked three times.

```
// index.xhtml (alt version, same behavior)
    <f:view>
       <h:body>
           <h3>Some Text</h3>
           <h:form id="dataEntryForm">
               <p:menubar id="menuBar" binding="#{dataEntryBean.menuBar}" />
               <p:dashboard id="dashboard" binding="#{dataEntryBean.dashboard}"/>
           </h:form>
       </h:body>
   </f:view>
```

For clarification, the bean is `@SessionScoped` and `@ManagedBean`.  I am testing all of this on Tomcat 8.0.33 with MyFaces 2.2.10.

---

Edit #2: Based on Kukeltje's request, stripped out some information that doesn't appear to be involved in the issue.

Comment: Does it work outside a tabview? Does it work when **not** using an include but directly in a page?

Comment: Updated OP with the results of Kukeltje's suggestion.

Comment: Right combination of scope and managedbean annotation? And please remove all the tabview and include stuff from the Q. It is not relevant and just creating possible noise

Comment: I am - in no uncertain terms - **not** a JSF expert so, at best, my only answer to your question can be "I think so."  :(

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces

Comment: Oh, ok, I get what you meant now.  Yes, both annotations are from the `javax.faces.bean` package.  (Off topic: If I could get OWB working on Tomcat, I would very much like to be using `@Named` but that's an entirely different issue.)