# Target Unreachable, identifier 'XXX' resolved to null - jakarta.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: maven, cdi, java-ee-7, mojarra, netbeans-14

I'm new to Java and tried to follow [this tutorial](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html). Since it's outdated, I've made some changes to use newer versions:

- Netbeans 14
- Glassfish 6
- Java EE7
- Jakarta Faces 3
- Mojarra 3.0.1

The tutorial consists of a form where a user submits a message and gets the total count. However, when I submit, I get

[image: error]

Any clue of what I'm missing?

Here are the Glassfish logs

When app runs

> WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public
> org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.ProcessAllAnnotatedTypes.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
> ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all
> annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or
> a generic type with bounds.|#]   WELD-000411: Observer method
> [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public
> org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
> ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types.
> Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type
> with bounds.|#]   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod]
> org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
> ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all
> annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or
> a generic type with bounds.|#]   WELD-000146:
> BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType) used for class
> com.ibm.jbatch.container.cdi.BatchProducerBean is deprecated from CDI
> 1.1!|#]   Initializing Soteria 2.0.1 for context '/mavenproject1'|#]   Initializing Mojarra 3.0.1 for context '/mavenproject1'|#]
> Monitoring jndi:/server/mavenproject1/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for
> modifications|#]   Loading application [mavenproject1] at
> [/mavenproject1]|#]   mavenproject1 was successfully deployed in 4,055
> milliseconds.|#]

When I click submit

> /index.xhtml @15,103 value="#{messageView.message.message}": Target
> Unreachable, identifier 'messageView' resolved to null
> jakarta.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @15,103
> value="#{messageView.message.message}": Target Unreachable, identifier
> 'messageView' resolved to null    at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:64)
> at
> com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:69)
> at
> jakarta.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1040)
> at jakarta.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:955)   at
> jakarta.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1232)    at
> jakarta.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:721)
> at jakarta.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:217)
> at
> jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:901)
> at
> jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:901)
> at
> jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1254)
> at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:49)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)     at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
> at
> jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:681)
> at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:437)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:440)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:34)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by:
> jakarta.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier
> 'messageView' resolved to null    at
> com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:148)   at
> com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:62)  at
> com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:160)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
> at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:62)
> ... 42 more

Here are some of the related files

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"     
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <h:form>
                <h:outputLabel value="Message:"/><h:inputText value="#{messageView.message.message}"/>
                <h:commandButton action="#{messageView.postMessage}" value="Post Message"/>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

MessageView.java

```
package my.presentation;

import boundary.MessageFacade;
import entities.Message;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;


@Named(value = "messageView")
@RequestScoped
public class MessageView {

    @EJB
    private MessageFacade messageFacade;
    private Message message;

    public MessageView() {
        this.message = new Message();
    }
    
    public Message getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
    
    public int getMessagesCount(){
        return messageFacade.findAll().size();
    }
    
    public String postMessage(){
        this.messageFacade.create(message);
        return "theend";
    }
}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
              version="3.0">

</faces-config>
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee 
                             https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<!--
    Copyright (c) 1997, 2018 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    
    This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
    terms of the Eclipse Public License v. 2.0, which is available at
    http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0.

    This Source Code may also be made available under the following Secondary
    Licenses when the conditions for such availability set forth in the
    Eclipse Public License v. 2.0 are satisfied: GNU General Public License,
    version 2 with the GNU Classpath Exception, which is available at
    https://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/license.html.

    SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0 WITH Classpath-exception-2.0
-->
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces) with no luck.

Comment: hello, try to add @ManagedBean(name="messageView") instead of @Named(name="messageView") viz. your link https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html, or try to add init() method with annotaction @PostConstruct where you should init "message" field

Comment: @MartinVolek The tutorial uses older versions that I've already updated;`@ManagedBean` is deprecated for CDI 3, so `@Named` must be used instead. `Message` is initialized in the constructor.

Comment: I guess jsf 3.0 is not supported by Jakarta EE7, try to chance jsf to 2.2 https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/zos?topic=architecture-supported-java-ee-7-8-feature-combinations, you also have to change beans version to 2.0

jsf version 2.3 is for Jakarta EE 8