# What's the difference between @Stateful and @SessionBean using JSF 2 and EJB 3.1?

Tags: java, jsf-2, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

They seen really a lot alike.

I know one is a View and one is a EJB but the behavior is almost identical as far as I can see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between jsf beans and ejb beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295303/difference-between-jsf-beans-and-ejb-beans)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused somewhere. There isn't any annotation called `@SessionBean` in either JSF 2.1 or EJB 3.1.

There is an [interface](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/ejb/SessionBean.html) by that name, but it's old, deprecated and you should forget it ever existed.

If you meant a `@SessionScoped` `@ManagedBean` vs a `@Stateful` bean, then the link CoolBeans posted should provide some context.