# What does adding the @Stateful or @Stateless annotations actually do?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm just getting to grips with Java EE. I know that adding `@Stateful` or `@Stateless` annotations to a class will make it an EJB bean. But what is actually happening in the background once I do that? I see the following listed on Wikipedia in relation to EJBs.

- Transaction processing
- Integration with the persistence services offered by the Java
  Persistence API (JPA)
- Concurrency control
- Eventing using Java Message Service and Java EE Connector
  Architecture
- Asynchronous method invocation

1. When I mark a class as an EJB do items listed above get 'taken care
   of' in the background? An entirely different code path is followed
   that goes through each of the above once I make a class an EJB, is
   that what's happening?
2. I see that using CDI I have the option of injecting EJB beans as oppposed to CDI beans. In that case should I always be using EJB beans instead of CDI beans as EJB beans are more powerful than CDI beans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487987/where-to-use-ejb-3-1-and-cdi/13504763#13504763) for some insight on both questions.

The highlights to focus on in that answer are that:

- EJBs and CDI beans are proxied components, the object you get is a fake, the real object is hidden and this is how services are added: caller->proxy->services->realObject
- CDI and EJB are effectively the same as such, mix them freely.  Which you use depends on what you're attempting to do.  I tend to use CDI unless I need one of the items listed in that answer.  Then I just upgrade or add a new bean.

Note, one thing I did miss in that answer was the entire `@MessageDriven` concept.

#### MessageDriven Beans

It's very interesting you put JMS / Connector on the same line as that is exactly how they are implemented.  Message-Driven Beans (MDBs) should actually be called "Connector-Driven Beans" as all communication and lifecycle of an MDB is actually tied to the Connector Architecture specification and has nothing to do with JMS directly -- JMS is just the only Connector people ever see.  [There's a great deal of potential there](http://blog.dblevins.com/2010/10/ejbnext-connectorbean-api-jax-rs-and.html).  Hopefully we'll see some improvements in Java EE 7.

Comment: >It's very interesting you put JMS / Connector on the same line - It's from the EJB Wikipedia article. I put this there for exactly the reason you mention ;) (the MDB explanation further down in the article should clarify this aspect, but I would preferable need a source to refer to. Not sure if this SO answer qualifies as a source though)