# EJB bean and CDI bean and Injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

After reading these,

- [Where to use EJB 3.1 and CDI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487987/where-to-use-ejb-3-1-and-cdi)
- [How do CDI and EJB compare? interact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684112/how-do-cdi-and-ejb-compare-interact)
  and some other articles.

I'm still confused over the following things, please correct me if i am wrong.

1. All classes within the same package as the bean.xml is a CDI bean
   except for classes annotate as session/message/singleton.
2. Only EJB can be injected using @EJB(within another EJB), while both
   CDI bean and EJB bean can be injected using @inject(within EJB bean
   or CDI bean).
3. class annotate as @Stateless(for example) that is injected using
   @Inject is still a EJB bean, not a CDI bean, and will still be
   managed by EJB container with all the goodness of pooling and
   transactional.

Thanks alot. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would make the following corrections:

1. All classes within the same **archive** as the beans.xml is a CDI bean, **including** EJBs.
2. Only EJB can be injected using `@EJB` (within another EJB **or any other EE managed object including CDI beans**), while both CDI bean and EJB bean can be injected using @inject (within EJB bean or CDI bean).
3. A class annotated as @Stateless (for example) that is injected using @Inject is still an EJB bean, **and it may also be** a CDI bean **if in a bean deployment archive**; **regardless**, it will still be managed by EJB container with all the goodness of pooling and transactional.

Notably, a CDI managed bean is anything that can be `@Inject`ed into another CDI bean and can itself use `@Inject`, which is true for all EJBs, and `@EJB` can be used to inject an EJB into any other EE managed bean (EJB, servlet, CDI managed bean, etc.).

Comment: That's all I need to know, for now. Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, you should click the "check mark" to the left of the answer to accept it.